# Why is the stator coil wrapped with layers of metal disks instead of a whole metal block?

Tags: motor, coil, stator

I don't know if this question belongs to this forum, but I just saw this video and found out that the stator coil's armor (? - or something, I don't know the word) is made of layers of metal disks, not a whole metal block as I thought it was. Why is that? Is it related to heat dissipation or something?

[Link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMPnZjNfA1g)

[image]

Comment: By any chance could you add a link to the video?

Comment: The word you're looking for is armature, for future reference.

Comment: @hacktastical I've added the link to the video on the post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The stator core is ‘laminated’. This means that the stator windings are wound on a core made up of thin plates that are insulated from each other.

The reason for laminating is to reduce eddy currents and the losses associated with them. Laminating breaks up the eddy current paths into multiple smaller layers, which makes the electrical impedance to the eddies much higher.

This is also done with transformers and other types of coils for the same reason.

More here: https://www.brainkart.com/article/Transformer--Principle-of-Operation_12139/

And here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237181/transformers-laminating-the-core

Comment: Basically: the core should conduct magnetism, but not conduct electricity (in the relevant directions).